# BMC Atrium CMDB - normalization status is 30 even I have set normalization configuration

Tags: cmdb

I have a customized class called classA and the dataset is called datasetA. The classA is added in class configuration and the datasetA is added in dataset configuration. After that, I load the data via atrium integrator. I check the normalization status which is 30 and I suppose it is 20. How come?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the default in the Class Manager. 20 is the default and enforced by workflow on submit. However, your value of 30 tells me that you've not added the class to the Normalization Attribute Definitions form. 
Only the out of the box classes will be normalized.

You should use the Normalization Configuration panel to add the custom class to the list and decide how the Product catalog will normalize your entries by adding your product as Model, Manufacturer and Category, Type, Item (CTI) values. Else it will "Fail to normalize" once added.

For reference, here is the list of enumerations for that field:

### 530041601 - NormalizationStatus

Other;10

Not Normalized;20

Not Applicable For Normalization;30

Normalization Failed;40

Normalized but Not Approved;50

Normalized and Approved;60

Modified After Last Normalization;70